# Is this book excerpt an accurate statistical analysis of project risk?

Tags: probability, multivariate-analysis, risk

I found this passage on the odds of a project succeeding in a book on risk management.  I know this is open-ended, but is the author's math and logical reasoning correct here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**: The calculation only holds if the 6 steps are stochastically independent. Otherwise, the calculation is not accurate. (I.e., all 6 events must be drawn from independent distributions.) As a result, the success probability might be much lower. E.g., suppose that success of task one induces and 80% failure of task 5 because of resource allocations that are necessary to accomplish task 1 or any other reason.

**Problem 2**: How can the firm be certain about the estimted confidence intervals? (I know it's kind of a stickler thing to bring up, but the book is about risk management. Why not bother with managing the risk that you carry whilst managing risks?)